# Receiving websocket messages twice

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I'm retrieving data from an exchange by a private async websocket connection.
It works fine the only problem is that all messages are coming in double.
Any ideas what's wrong?

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json
import time
import auth
import hmac 
import pprint


api_key = auth.api_key
secret_key = auth.secret_key

async def handler():
    async with websockets.connect('wss://ftx.com/ws/') as ws:
        
        
        ts = int(time.time() * 1000)
        signature = hmac.new(secret_key.encode(), f'{ts}websocket_login'.encode(), 'sha256').hexdigest()
        auth = {'op': 'login', 'args': {'key': api_key,
                                    'sign': signature, 
                                    'time': ts,
                                    'subaccount':'python'
                                    }}
        await ws.send(json.dumps(auth))
        data = {'op': 'subscribe', 'channel': 'fills'}
        await ws.send(json.dumps(data))
        

        async for message in ws:
            
            data = json.loads(message)
          
            if data['type'] == 'update':
                pprint.pprint(data)
            
    return await data

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

t1 = loop.create_task(handler())

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(handler())
```

Comment: You are running two copies of `handler()`.  You either create a task or pass the function to `run_until_complete`.  Not both.

Comment: it works. thanks!!